# Oracle stored procedure creation from C# code fails for PL/SQL developer

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, procedure

I tried to create a SQL procedure on an Oracle server. Here is my code,

```
private const string InsertCallProc =
        @"CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTCALL (Id in varchar2,No in varchar2,
           Surname in varchar2, Name in varchar2, CallType in varchar2,
           CallDate in date, CallNo in varchar2, VoiceNetwork in varchar2,
           Type in varchar2,TalkTime in number,PriceWithDiscount in number,
           PriceWithoutDiscount in number, LmTime in date)
        AS
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO TMOBILE_R_CALLS (ID,NO,SURNAME,NAME,CALL_TYPE,CALL_DATE,CALL_NO, 
                    VOICE_NETWORK, TYPE,TALK_TIME, PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT, PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,LM_TIME)
                VALUES(Id, No, Surname, Name, CallType,CallDate, CallNo, VoiceNetwork,Type, TalkTime, 
                    PriceWithDiscount,PriceWithoutDiscount, LmTime);
    END;";
```

Method with execute this sql cmd, input parameter is `InsertCallProc` field.

```
    private void ExecuteNonQueryCmd(string cmdText)
    {
        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(GenerateConnectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = new OracleCommand
            {
                Connection = conn,
                CommandText = cmdText
            };

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I called this method, the procedure is created. But if I check the procedure in PL/SQL developer I see this:

> Compilation errors for PROCEDURE SYSTEM.INSERTCALL
>
> Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>    
>   current Line: 1 Text: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTCALL (Id in
>   varchar2,No in varchar2,

I think this is caused by formatting the string in C# code. Because if I execute the same SQL code on Oracle server procedure is created without problems.

What is a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Do not create tables or stored procedures in the schema SYSTEM. This is a very bad idea. It might not be the cause of your immediate problem but cause a lot of other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's the newlines embedded in your C# string. The error

> Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following

indicates to me that there's a special character that's not printable being encountered. It's also indicating that the problem is in the first line.

Also, it's generally a Bad Idea to create objects in the SYSTEM or SYS schemas.

As for the answers pointing the finger at reserved word use: while it's not a very good practice, it is likely not the culprit here:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p(TYPE IN VARCHAR2) IS
  2  BEGIN
  3    dbms_output.put_line(TYPE);
  4  END;
  5  /

Procedure created
SQL> DECLARE
  2  BEGIN
  3    p('This is a test');
  4  END;
  5  /

This is a test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to the naming. You've got a parameter and a column both called `Type`, which according to this [page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm) is a reserved word.

I'd also be very reluctant to have the same names for the parameters as for the columns. I'd prefix the parameters with `in` or similar, so I'd have something like `inId` instead of just `Id`.

All in all, I'd suggest that one way to test it would be to change the code to create a very basic procedure without parameters, that does nothing, and see if that works, if it does, then add on one parameter etc until it breaks.

Comment: While not a good practice, the reserved word use is not the problem here. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrong with this conclusion:

> Because if I execute the same SQL code on Oracle server procedure is
>   created without problems.

Procedure created without errors, and then compiled with errors - but silently.

If you use [sqlplus](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ#What_is_SQL.2APlus_and_where_does_it_come_from.3F) or [sqlplusw](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a92157/ch3.htm#1005640) just execute [`SHOW ERRORS`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1013398) command immediately after creating procedure.

If you use advanced development tools like [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev6.html), [TOAD](http://www.quest.com/toad/), [SQL Navigator](http://www.quest.com/sql-navigator/) or [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) just open created function in dedicated editor window and try to compile it here. You must see the same compilation errors.

At any case you must fix some errors in procedure code: usage of reserved words(`type`) as parameter name and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Thak you for answer, problem was in formating string in C#. I solved with this:

```
    public static string CreateInsertCallProc =
            "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTCALL (inId in varchar2,inSimCard in varchar2,\n" +
                "inSurname in varchar2, inName in varchar2, inCallType in varchar2,\n" +
                "inCallDate in date, inCallNo in varchar2, inVoiceNetwork in varchar2,\n" +
                "inTimeType in varchar2,inTalkTime in number,inPriceWithDiscount in number,\n" +
                "inPriceWithoutDiscount in number, inLmTime in date)\n" +
            "AS\n" +
                "BEGIN\n" +
                    "INSERT INTO TMOBILE_R_CALLS (ID,SIM_CARD,SURNAME,NAME,CALL_TYPE,CALL_DATE,CALL_NO,\n" +
                        "VOICE_NETWORK, TIME_TYPE,TALK_TIME, PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT, PRICE_WITHOUT_DISCOUNT,LM_TIME)\n" +
                    "VALUES(inId, inSimCard, inSurname, inName, inCallType, inCallDate, inCallNo, inVoiceNetwork,\n" +
                        " inTimeType, inTalkTime,inPriceWithDiscount,inPriceWithoutDiscount, inLmTime);\n" +
        "END;";
```

Also I change columne name from Type to Time_Type, and move table from schema system